# mudar o userModel do Authenticator do CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou utilizando uma tabela com nome ga_usuario para gestão de acesso, gerei o esqueleto com bake no cakePHP e o controller ficou GaUsuarioController, o problema é que quando vou logar ele fala que a tabela users não existe, a pergunta é, como posso setar o userModel para o meu modelo ?

Meu apllication.php esta com a seguinte função para autenticação:

```
    public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
{
    $service = new AuthenticationService();
    $service->setConfig([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/cake-erp/GaUsuario/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);

    $fields = [
        'username' => 'usuario',
        'password' => 'senha'
    ];

    // Load the authenticators, you want session first
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
        'fields' => $fields,
        'loginUrl' => '/cake-erp/GaUsuario/login'
    ]);

    // Load identifiers
    $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields'));

    return $service;
}
```

Mesmo adicionando o 'UserModel' => 'GaUsuario' ele não identifica e continua dando erro, vejam o erro abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

para quem ja teve esse problema, de utilizar uma tabela diferente para os usuarios, é necessário alterar o ORM resolver que se encontra em : vendor\cakephp\authentication\src\Identifier\Resolver\OrmResolver
alterando o'userModel' => 'nomeDoSeuModelo'

ou passar via parametro.

Answer (score 0):

A passagem via paramentros seria assim. Descobri após ter feito funcionar alterando o OrmResolver.

https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/migration-from-the-authcomponent.html#migrate-authcomponent-settings

public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/usuarios/login',
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

```
    // Load identifiers, ensure we check email and password fields
    $authenticationService->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [

        'resolver' => [    <<=================== incluir
            'className' => 'Authentication.Orm', <<=======
            'userModel' => 'Usuarios', <<===========
        ],

        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
        ]
    ]);

    // Load the authenticators, you want session first
    $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    // Configure form data check to pick email and password
    $authenticationService->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Form', [
        'fields' => [
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
        ],
        'loginUrl' => '/usuarios/login',
    ]);

    return $authenticationService;
}
```